# Delphi - Missing class/object in specific project only

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe3, indy10

Today I got around a very strange issue on opening my XE3 ide for Delphi.
A specific project group, where I have over dozen of projects, and which was working fine up until yesterday, started to show me error on opening, **stating that an Indy TIdUDPServer class is missing.** .

The reported error was reffering to one of the projects inside the project group, which I haven't touched nor changed for over 2 months now, other than run -> therefore it was selected by default, and as such tried to load it's default form on startup, which have the UDPServer component dropped on it.

To make it strange and not understandable: The mentioned project builds just fine, and has UDPServer component on it that works just fine, also in the code (.pas) the component is found and can be manipulated without errors - I just can't get the form to show.

Furthermore, if I close the project group, and open another project that contains TIdUDPServer component, that one loads just fine. If I afterwards load the mentioned project group again, the main form that raised errors the first time, loads just fine and I can edit it normally.

On restarting IDE the same thing happens again, and error persists.

The error on starting IDE and selecting the project group (aka trying to load the problematic form for the first time) reports this:

```
Cannot open file "C:\Delphi\MyProjectName\IdUDPServer". The system cannot find the file 
specified. Ignore the error and continue? NOTE: Ignoring the error may cause
components to be deleted or property values to be lost.
```

while from the next time I try to load the form (closing .pas file, loading another form, and trying to open the problematic form again) further on, it states the same error but with path being

> "C:\Windows\system32\IdUDPServer".

The form and pas file's last change date is December 2015, as well as the project itself. I've only added 2 new projects to the project group, but that was over 2 weeks ago, so no other changes appeared since yesterday when all this was still working fine.
No updates, no IDE changes, no new installs, nothing that would come on my mind.

Anyone got any idea what could be causing this, and how to overcome/solve the issue?

Thanks!

Comment: If you could produce an error message verbatim that would help, rather than describing things. Be precise. Copy/paste the error.

Comment: The error is literally rewritten in the code block above. I can add a partial screenshot though, if proof is what you wish?

Comment: OK. I see it now. The question could be more concise. It seems you've changed something though.

Comment: I've checked, and none of the files of the project, nor the project file itself has been changed since december. Windows reports that dates as well, and so does my memory. 
The one thing that really doesn't get in my mind though is why would it load the form just fine then after some other project that includes the UDPServer component?  It doesn't seem logical at all. Any ideas where/what to check?

Comment: Likely your Delphi or components that changed. Hard to advise with the facts we have.

Comment: Try to open just the single project from the group instead of the whole group.

Comment: Did that, same result. Opening the same project and/or projectgroup on another computer installed same IDE does reproduce the error though, so this must obviously be something in the project itself, not the IDE.  :/

Answer (score 0):

If idudpserver.pas is mentioned in the .dpr with a wrong path, strange things may happen. As soon as it can no longer use the old DCU, it starts looking for the source, expects it at the path, and there is the error.

In general I avoid adding files to the dpr unless they are "local" to the project

Comment: This is the main form of the dpr project, the project has not been modified or changed in anyway, and all of the units that are included in the project are in the local path of the .dpr file.
Regardless of that, would, if your example would be the case, the project still open the form later if IDE would detect the IdUDPServer from another "healthy" project...?

Comment: And no, .dpr does not include idudpserver. only the main form does.

Comment: So where is the source for idudpserver and how can the ide find it? If you don't know that then you have a problem.

Comment: And/or clean out .dcu's.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan The source of idUdpServer is inside the Indy10 folder inside the installation folder of the IDE. That's where every declaration of the IdUDPServer takes me, at least.
Note that with the error given the .pas source file still opens, while form is not accessible. And from that source file I CAN go to the IdUDPServer declaration just fine and get the component's source code. It also compiles just fine, it's just that the form is not generated/previewed for some reason. So the IDE must know about the component orelse it would not compile, or am I wrong here?

Comment: The weird thing though is that the error complains it cannot find the component inside the "C:\Windows\system32\" folder. That is what I have no idea about why it searches through that path.